# Adding a Div into another Div with DOM JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a netflix type effect with CSS and JavaScript where things are displayed on a carousel using flexbox and trying to add the flex item into the container with JavaScript as am using an API to get data so never know how many elements there will be but nothing it working with the JavaScript.

```
const container = document.getElementById("container");
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.className = "item";
var arr = ["1","1","1"];

const map = arr.map(x => {return `<div>${x}</div>`});
console.log(map)
map.forEach(function(element){
    newDiv.innerHTML = element;
    container.append(newDiv)
});
```

The container has the class container and the extra divs have the class items

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>
    <!--Title for the Page-->
    <h1 id="title">Will and Amys Movie App</h1>

    <!--Grid Layout-->
    <div id="container">
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: container is null
    <anonymous> file:///D:/Github/MovieSummerProject22/script.js:8
    <anonymous> file:///D:/Github/MovieSummerProject22/script.js:4
script.js:8:5
    <anonymous> file:///D:/Github/MovieSummerProject22/script.js:8
    map self-hosted:180
    <anonymous> file:///D:/Github/MovieSummerProject22/script.js:4
```

Answer (score 1):

change your `newDiv.innerHTML = element;` to `newDiv.innerHTML += element;`

Also this can be improved a bit and you can use only the `map`, no need to loop twice

Note that you are creating an extra `div`, that you don't want.

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const arr = ["1", "1", "1"];

arr.map(x => {
  const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.className = "item";
  newDiv.innerHTML += x;
  container.append(newDiv)
});
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: it still says that the container is null thought?

Comment: I don't see  it in your question, your question is about `am using an API to get data so never know how many elements there will be but nothing it working with the JS.`, so it is about the elements.
Also did you see my snippet w/ improved code?

Comment: Yeah so i am using the array as the data so far and yeah I changed the code to do this and it still days null and not adding anything to the screen

Comment: container being `null`  means that your selector doesn't exist in your html, in my snippet exists and it works, do you have this `<div id="container"></div>` ?

Comment: ```<body>
    <!--Title for the Page-->
    <h1 id="title">Will and Amys Movie App</h1>

    <!--Grid Layout-->
    <div id="container">
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</body>``` that is everything in my body

Comment: create a snippet

Comment: Creating the snippet

Comment: also is unclear to me if you want to add multiple div `item` inside `container`, or you want to have multiple `div` inside  one `item`

Comment: So the main div is the container and it would have many divs inside that container that will all have the same class because they will all look the same

Comment: ok then your code is wrong,  because is creating 2 divs, one `item` and another inside `item`, this os the output of your code `<div id="container"><div class="item"><div>1</div></div></div>`

Comment: how would i counteract this?

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: It still adds nothing to the HTML though?

Comment: where is the snippet ?

Comment: the snippet for what?

Comment: to see your problem that you are mentioning, you say its still empty or/and the container is `null`, so set a snippet where we can see this errors

Comment: Added the snippet

Comment: that's not a snippet LOL, see what is a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Just found out the issue was that the script tag was at the start of the html where non of the elements had been made so changed to the bottom and then it worked and added the elements thanks for the help